# Failed to download vulnerability DB - Trivy by aquasecurity

Tags: docker, trivy

I'm trying to run security scan on docker images with [Trivy](https://github.com/aquasecurity/trivy). Docker run throws error
`failed to download vulnerability DB: DB file not found` any reason why?

**Command:**

```sh
$ mkdir /tmp/trivy
$ docker run --rm -v /tmp/trivy:/root/.cache/ aquasec/trivy python:3.4-alpine
```

**Error:**

```sh
2021-03-03T09:55:22.770Z        WARN    You should avoid using the :latest tag as it is cached. You need to specify '--clear-cache' option when :latest image is changed
2021-03-03T09:55:22.771Z        INFO    Need to update DB
2021-03-03T09:55:22.771Z        INFO    Downloading DB...
2021-03-03T09:55:23.309Z        FATAL   failed to download vulnerability DB: failed to download vulnerability DB: DB file not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ridiculous as it sounds. It turned out that my network was blocking download. Switching to **tethered internet** from my mobile device solved the problem.